# OpenVZ kernel panic

Tags: centos5, openvz

I recently installed OpenVZ on my VMWare box (To do some testing) and I get the following:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p38btkv5j84bvsh/Capture.JPG

the GRUB config is as follows:

```
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
#          initrd /initrd-version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title OpenVZ (2.6.32-042stab057.1)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-042stab057.1 ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 sysfs.deprecated=1
        initrd /initrd-2.6.32-042stab057.1.img
title CentOS (2.6.18-238.el5)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-238.el5 ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
        initrd /initrd-2.6.18-238.el5.img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one usually occur when you are installing OpenVZ on wrong repo.I assume that the host node operating system that you are using is CentOS 5.To fix this you need to reinstall again your OpenVZ.

First you must remove the OpenVZ.After that try to edit the repository of OpenVZ at **/etc/yum.conf.d/openvz.repo**

You should find something similar like this.You no need to change the line enabled from 0 to 1 :

```
[openvz-kernel-rhel5]
name=OpenVZ RHEL5-based kernel
#baseurl=http://download.openvz.org/kernel/branches/rhel5-2.6.18/current/
mirrorlist=http://download.openvz.org/kernel/mirrors-rhel5-2.6.18
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://download.openvz.org/RPM-GPG-Key-OpenVZ
```

Don't forget to change other settings(openvz-kernel-rhel4 and openvz-kernel-rhel5) to enabled=0.

After editing that file,run this command :

```
yum install ovzkernel
```

You should good to go.